# Prove that $a\sqrt{b^3+1}+b\sqrt{c^3+1}+c\sqrt{a^3+1} \leq 5$

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, rearrangement-inequality

Let $a,b,c$ be nonnegative real numbers such that $a+b+c=3$. Prove that
$$a\sqrt{b^3+1}+b\sqrt{c^3+1}+c\sqrt{a^3+1} \leq 5$$
I found a point at which the equality is attended, say $a=0,b=1,c=2$. But I have no idea how to prove it. I tried to use the AM-GM inequality but then I obtained the more difficult one. Please help me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\text{WLOG b=mid(a,b,c)} $

By AM-GM and Rearrangement we have:

$$\text{L.H.S}=\sum _{cyc}a\sqrt{b^3+1}=\sum _{cyc}a\sqrt{\left(b+1\right)\left(b^2-b+1\right)}$$

$$\le \sum _{cyc}a\cdot \frac{b+1+b^2-b+1}{2}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{2a+ab^2}{2}=\frac{ab^2+bc^2+ca^2}{2}+3$$

$$\le \frac{b\left(a^2+ac+c^2\right)}{2}+3\le \frac{b\left(a+c\right)^2}{2}+3$$

$$=\frac{2b\left(a+c\right)^2}{4}+3\le \frac{\left(\frac{2\left(a+b+c\right)}{3}\right)^3}{4}+3=5=\text{R.H.S}$$

Comment: In the middle, you use $ab^2 + ca^2 \le ba^2 + abc$. Can you explain?

Comment: $ab^2+bc^2+ca^2\le a^2b +abc+bc^2$  It is rearrangement inequality. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality and here https://brilliant.org/wiki/rearrangement-inequality/

Comment: Yes, takes a little reordering, I got it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think you can not assume that $a\geq b\geq c$ since the inequality is not symmetric.

Comment: I have the same idea as @Maria Mazur that we cannot assume that $a \geq b \geq c$. We can see that if $a$ is the minimal among them, say $c=0$, then we must have $b=1$ and $a=2$ and cannot attend equality at $c=0,b=2,a=1$. It means the ordering is important here. We can assume only $c = \min (a,b,c)$ or $a=\max (a,b,c)$.

Comment: Here we can assume $b$ is middle among $a,b,c$ and get the result. Thank you.

Comment: Very nice derivation: congratulations!

Answer (score 1):

Start out as before:
$$
a\sqrt{b^{3}+1}+b\sqrt{c^{3}+1}+c\sqrt{a^{3}+1}\leq5
$$

$$
a\cdot\sqrt{\left(b+1\right)\left(b^{2}-b+1\right)}\leq a\cdot\frac{b^{2}+2}{2}
$$

$$
\frac{a\left(b^{2}+1\right)+b\left(c^{2}+1\right)+c\left(a^{2}+1\right)}{2}=3+\frac{ab^{2}+bc^{2}+ca^{2}}{2}
$$
Continue by lagrange multipliers:
$$
\Lambda=ab^{2}+bc^{2}+ca^{2}+\lambda\left(a+b+c-3\right)
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
\partial_{a}\Lambda=b^{2}+2ac-\lambda & \Rightarrow\lambda=b^{2}+2ac\\
\partial_{b}\Lambda=c^{2}+2ab-\lambda & \Rightarrow\lambda=c^{2}+2ab\\
\partial_{c}\Lambda=a^{2}+2bc-\lambda & \Rightarrow\lambda=a^{2}+2bc
\end{cases}
$$

$$
H=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
2c & 2b & 2a & 1\\
2b & 2a & 2c & 1\\
2a & 2c & 2b & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$

$$
b^{2}+2ac=c^{2}+2ab\Rightarrow(b-c)\left(b+c-2a\right)=0
$$

$$
(b-c)\left(b+c-2a\right)=(a-c)\left(a+c-2b\right)=(a-b)\left(a+b-2c\right)=0
$$

If we have no two equal, then we arrive at a contradiction:

$$
b+c-2a=a+c-2b=a+b-2c=0\Rightarrow a=b=c
$$

Hence assume $a-b=0$, then either $a-c=0$ and getting $a=b=c=1$,
or: $a+c-2a=0\Rightarrow a=c$ yielding the same results. Hence the
only candidate where $abc\neq0$ is:

$$
a=b=c=1
$$

Here, we get:

$$
ab^{2}+bc^{2}+ca^{2}=3
$$

Assume $b=0$ if we are on the boundary, then by AM-GM:

$$
ab^{2}+bc^{2}+ca^{2}=ca^{2}=\frac{1}{2}\left(2\left(3-a\right)a^{2}\right)\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2\left(3-a\right)+a+a}{3}\right)^{3}=4
$$

Hence we have

$$
\frac{ab^{2}+bc^{2}+ca^{2}}{2}\leq2
$$

As needed (maybe not too detailed why the $a=b=c=1$ is a saddle point). THe surface is shown below:
[image: Plotted out the surface in 2 variables]